# Find common element between multiple vectors (no integer elements)

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a C++ function that can find the common element between multiple vectors? The vector elements are **not** integers (in my case the elements are of type QPair).

The function would ideally have a set of vectors as an argument (the number of vectors to compare can vary) and return the common value of the vectors. I have ensured that there are no duplicates in each vector, but it is possible that there is no common element.

Example:

```
vec 1 [a,b]      vec 2 [c,d,a,e,h]     vec 3 [i,j,a]
```

Common value to return:

```
a
```

Comment: Yes for pre-sorted collections: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Comment: There is nothing built in for this but there are algorithms that can help.  Are these vectors sorted?

Comment: i'm still unfamiliar with the concept of sorting non-integer/non-string arrays. but no the vectors are not sorted

Comment: std::sort will sort containers of any type which has a < operator

Comment: @ginhill For that see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects)

Comment: @NathanOliver ok ty, in that case i can probably sort the vectors. in that case what algorithms can help solve my problem ?

Comment: @ginhill See the first comment by Richard Critten

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note, that `QPair` defines an [`operator<`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpair.html#operator-lt). However, `QPair` is a template and you didn't mention the types of first and second which are paired. So, for proper operation those first and second type have to provide an `operator<` as well.

Comment: yes it's a qpair of strings so no problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make them into hash table and count them out. As soon as you found them again, bump counter. If counter for particular item is the same as number of vectors, you got yourself an intersection. No need to pre-sort vector of pairs, define weak or string ordering etc.

Along the lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>

using Qpair = uint32_t; // should be std::pair<int, int> or similar
using Qpairs = std::vector<Qpair>;

int intersections(const std::list<Qpairs>& allpairs) {
    std::unordered_map<Qpair, int> m; // element vs counter

    auto count = allpairs.size(); // number of vectors to scan

    for(const auto& pairs: allpairs) { // loop over all vectors
        for (const auto& p : pairs) { // loop over elements in particular vector
            m[p] += 1;                // and count them
        }
    }

    int total_count = 0; // how many common elements are here
    for (const auto& e : m) {
        if (e.second == count) {
            ++total_count;
            // you could add e.first to output vector as well
        }
    }
    return total_count;
}

int main() {
    Qpairs v1{ 4, 2, 6, 8, 9 };
    Qpairs v2{ 1, 3, 8, 9, 4 };
    Qpairs v3{ 2, 8, 9, 5, 0 };

    std::list<Qpairs> l{ v1, v2, v3 };

    auto q = intersections(l);

    std::cout << q << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As Richard mentioned in comment, intersection can be done easily with [`std::set_intersection()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection). The pre-condition are sorted containers.

Thereby, the "set" in `set_intersection()` could be understood rather in a mathematical sense – it is not limited to `std::set`. A sorted `std::vector` can be used as well.

To sort a `std::vector`, [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) can be used. In this case, the pre-condition is a possible order of elements i.e. the `operator<` is defined for the element type.

`QPair` defines an [`operator<`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpair.html#operator-lt) which can be used if the types of `first` and `second` do as well.

As the OP didn't mention which types are `QPair`ed, I chose `std::string` and `double` for my sample `isectQPair.cc`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <QtCore>

int main()
{
  // prepare sample data
  typedef QPair<std::string, double> Pair;
  Pair
    a("Hello", 1.23),
    b("World", 2.34),
    c("Stack", 3.45),
    d("Overflow", 4.56),
    e("C++11", 5.67),
    f("C++14", 6.78),
    g("C++17", 7.89),
    h("C++20", 8.90),
    i("gin hill", 10.1),
    j("scheff", 0.0);
  std::vector<Pair> vec1({ a, b });
  std::vector<Pair> vec2({ c, d, a, e, h });
  std::vector<Pair> vec3({ i, j, a });
  // sort vectors
  std::sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end());
  std::sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
  std::sort(vec3.begin(), vec3.end());
  // intersect vectors
  std::vector<Pair> isect12;
  std::set_intersection(
    vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end(),
    std::back_inserter(isect12));
  std::vector<Pair> isect123;
  std::set_intersection(
    isect12.begin(), isect12.end(), vec3.begin(), vec3.end(),
    std::back_inserter(isect123));
  // report
  const size_t n = isect123.size();
  std::cout << "Intersection contains " << n << " elements"
    << (n ? ':' : '.') << '\n';
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    const Pair &entry = isect123[i];
    std::cout << (i + 1) << ".: '" << entry.first
      << "', " << entry.second << '\n';
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

`isectQPair.pro`:

```
SOURCES = isectQPair.cc

Qt = core
```

Compiled and tested on [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 isectQPair.pro

$ make

$ ./isectQPair
Intersection contains 1 elements:
1.: 'Hello', 1.23

$
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/BuKjNH)</kbd> (`QPair` replaced with `std::pair`)

---

Another nice Q/A concerning intersection can be found here: [SO: how to find the intersection of two std::set in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13448064/7478597).